# Regex negative match on multiple column with and operator in AWK

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I have simple file with sample log:

```
192.168.1.117   60921   224.0.0.252     5355  yahoo.com
192.168.1.117   60900   192.168.1.118   5356  118.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa
192.29.1.221   5943    211.29.132.12   4325  webex.com
192.168.1.221   5943    192.29.132.12   4325  lizzard.com
```

I am using awk in following way to filter internal traffic and arpa domain:

`awk '($1 !~ ^([192.168]|[192.29]) && $3 !~ ^([192.168]|[192.29])) || $5 ~ (in\-addr\.arpa$)' < filein`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I am not getting any output?

Comment: Why `^([192.168]|[192.29])` instead of `^192\.(168|192)`?

Comment: agree for this particular sample it would work ^192\.(168|192) but i might have different IP ranges to filter e.g. 192.168.0.0, 172.16.0.0 hence using ^([192.168]|[172.16]) can give me better control. but point well taken for similar subnet thx

Comment: @BiscUI I don't think you quite understand character classes: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to wrap the regular expression between `//`. Furthermore the use of `[]` is wrong.

It should be:

```
awk '($1 !~ /^192\.(168|29)/ && $3 !~ /^192\.(168|29)/) || $5 ~ /in\-addr\.arpa$/' file
```

Comment: Thanks perfect tried wrap around and works as expected